# Does a 3x7 front derailleur works on a 3x9 setup

Tags: compatibility, derailleur-front

Will a 3 speed front derailleur meant for a a 3x7 setup work the same on a 3x9 setup?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. With so many variations, it would be helpful to give more specific details on what you are trying to change.  Brand and model numbers are a place to start, and be very specific about what you are attempting.  Edit your question to add this information and be prepared to further update the question as other comments are posted on it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, yes.

I have an old MTB that started as a 3x5, and I changed the cassette/chain/rear mech and rear shifter to a 9 speed Deore.   The chainrings are also unchanged.

The front derailleur works okay, after I slightly narrowed the width of the front derailleur's cage using slipjaw pliers.   This is because the chain is slightly narrower than 6/7/8 speed chain, and here its enough to matter.

[image]